# Why does Doctrine 2's autoloader try to get the Exception entity when I throw an exception?

Tags: php, exception, doctrine-orm

This is the relevant code:

```
throw new Exception("Message");
```

And this is the error message I get:

> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp\www\drupal-7.15\sites\all\modules\dbManip\Entities\Exception.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear\') in
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on line
>   163

I believe Doctrine is trying to load the `Exception` class definition as if it were just another entity of mine, but as far as I know, `Exception` is native to PHP (I'm using PHP 5.3.13). My theory is that I did something wrong concerning the autoloader, but I'm not sure what. Here is what I have concerning the autoloader:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

require_once("Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php");
Setup::registerAutoloadPEAR();

$classloader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__);
$classloader->register();
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can use throw an exception without doctrine's autoloader trying to load the `Exception` entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is PHP at play. Not Doctrine.

When you declare your file in a namespace, it will use the same namespace for all classes mentioned in the file. To indicate the Exception class is from the root namespace, you must make it explicit.

```
throw new \Exception("Message");
```